# Create multiple page form in Cocoa

Tags: cocoa, forms, animation

I want to create a form with iOS like transitions (in a Cocoa desktop application) between the form input. For instance, the user would input information to the form and click next to continue to input the remainder of the information. On the last form, the user would click submit. Upon clicking next, the form would have an animated transition, like on the iPhone before displaying the next set of forms. Sort of like how Turbo Tax ask a ton of questions before allowing you to submit that grouped information.

What would be the best approach to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 0):

This is commonly referred to as a wizard.

You basically have two options:

- Use a tabless tab view, following Apple's sample code in AnimatingTabView from http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#samplecode/Reducer/Introduction/Intro.html
- Manually swap the views in and out yourself.

There are pros and cons to both approaches.  Which you choose will probably depend on your requirements.  One issue with Core Animation on the desktop is lack of subpixel rendering for layer-backed views.  This is mostly an issue with text display but some people find it not to be an issue.

Answer (score 0):

I've needed this functionality a few times. I used this [tutorial](http://www.cimgf.com/2008/03/03/core-animation-tutorial-wizard-dialog-with-transitions/) to get started.